# ajax json response parseerror & syntaxerror

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a few AJAX functions that return a response of JSON dataType. However, it appears that there is some limit on the server, and no error when I run the script locally.

**The AJAX code:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'alterajax.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {value},
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(data){
    //at the moment for testing
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

**The PHP:**

```
$alterquery = $connection->prepare("SELECT tracking_type, tracking_change_date, tracking_effective_date, IFNULL(vessel_fcm_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_fcm_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_hull_id_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_hull_id_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_flag_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_flag_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_name_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_name_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_length_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_length_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_manufacturer_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_manufacturer_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_manufacturer_id_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_manufacturer_id_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_year_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_year_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_value_new, ''), IFNULL(vessel_value_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_id_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_id_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_street_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_street_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_city_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_city_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_state_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_state_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_zip_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_zip_old, ''), IFNULL(owner_country_new, ''), IFNULL(owner_country_old, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_id_new, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_id_old, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_street_new, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_street_old, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_city_new, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_city_old, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_state_new, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_state_old, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_zip_new, ''), IFNULL(loss_payee_zip_old, ''), IFNULL(base_id_new, ''), IFNULL(base_id_old, ''), IFNULL(policy_id_new, ''), IFNULL(policy_id_old, ''), IFNULL(policy_start_date_new, ''), IFNULL(policy_start_date_old, ''), IFNULL(policy_end_date_new, ''), IFNULL(policy_end_date_old, ''), IFNULL(vessel_fcm, ''), IFNULL(vessel_hull_id, ''), IFNULL(vessel_name, ''), IFNULL(vessel_manufacturer_id, '') FROM tracking WHERE tracking_type = ? ORDER BY tracking_change_date DESC LIMIT 20");
$alterquery->bind_param("i", $trackingtype);
$trackingtype = 333;
$alterquery->execute();
$alterquery->bind_result($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $tracking_effective_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_hull_id_old, $vessel_flag_new, $vessel_flag_old, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_length_old, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_old, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_old, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_year_old, $vessel_value_new, $vessel_value_old, $owner_id_new, $owner_id_old, $owner_street_new, $owner_street_old, $owner_city_new, $owner_city_old, $owner_state_new, $owner_state_old, $owner_zip_new, $owner_zip_old, $owner_country_new, $owner_country_old, $loss_payee_id_new, $loss_payee_id_old, $loss_payee_street_new, $loss_payee_street_old, $loss_payee_city_new, $loss_payee_city_old, $loss_payee_state_new, $loss_payee_state_old, $loss_payee_zip_new, $loss_payee_zip_old, $base_id_new, $base_id_old, $policy_id_new, $policy_id_old, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_start_date_old, $policy_end_date_new, $policy_end_date_old, $vessel_fcm, $vessel_hull_id, $vessel_name, $vessel_manufacturer_id);
while ($alterquery->fetch()){
    $data[] = array($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $tracking_effective_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_fcm_old, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_hull_id_old, $vessel_flag_new, $vessel_flag_old, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_name_old, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_length_old, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_old, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_old, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_year_old, $vessel_value_new, $vessel_value_old, $owner_id_new, $owner_id_old, $owner_street_new, $owner_street_old, $owner_city_new, $owner_city_old, $owner_state_new, $owner_state_old, $owner_zip_new, $owner_zip_old, $owner_country_new, $owner_country_old, $loss_payee_id_new, $loss_payee_id_old, $loss_payee_street_new, $loss_payee_street_old, $loss_payee_city_new, $loss_payee_city_old, $loss_payee_state_new, $loss_payee_state_old, $loss_payee_zip_new, $loss_payee_zip_old, $base_id_new, $base_id_old, $policy_id_new, $policy_id_old, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_start_date_old, $policy_end_date_new, $policy_end_date_old, $vessel_fcm, $vessel_hull_id, $vessel_name, $vessel_manufacturer_id);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**ERROR:**

> Status: parsererror
>   Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>   Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position: 0

Not sure what is causing this. I have 2 other ajax calls that are very similar to this (just selecting from different tables, however not as much data and they return in JSON fine)

Comment: is it possible you have some whitespace after your closing tag `?>`? Could you try removing it, as it is optional in a php only file.

Comment: @Sean that did not work

Comment: what does your returned json look like? can you access the php code page directly to see what the output is?

Comment: Is this a Godaddy server? Try adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` just before your `echo`

Comment: @Sean if I access directly, it is " null " ... but this is the same for the other AJAX ones formatted similar to what I have above, and that are working fine

Comment: @Phil namecheap! and that did not work!

Comment: maybe add a `$connection->error;`. As you are only creating `$data` in the loop, when your query fails or doesn't return any rows, than `$data` is null.

Comment: Add `$data = [];` before your `while` loop. I don't think this is the problem but it's just good practice

Comment: @Sean well, i added an if statement before the loop, and no error is found, the query runs fine

Comment: @Phil I initialized the array and I just get an empty array instead of null now

Comment: @Sean I am running this code exactly as I've shown above, locally on my PC with no errors. SO I'm guessing it has to do with something of the hosting provider

Comment: @Sean please see my answer below. It looks like the encoding was off, but this only triggered after a certain amount of data was sent back in json format. Is it possible the server could be set up this way or to require a specific encoding (utf-8) after a certain number of characters ? Locally testing, I did not have to use this function.

Comment: @Phil please see my answer below. It looks like the encoding was off, but this only triggered after a certain amount of data was sent back in json format. Is it possible the server could be set up this way or to require a specific encoding (utf-8) after a certain number of characters ? Locally testing, I did not have to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

After the whileloop, this is what fixed the issue of not receiving the data.

```
function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}

echo json_encode(utf8_converter($data));
```

Possible that the server is setup for a specific encoding (utf-8) ?